# Code efficiency. Effective way of using loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, switch-statement, performance

I am building a framework for a web application and would like to perform certain simple tasks like input retrieval and displaying them. Below is have the code, I feel the code can be improved and isn't efficient. Note:All three methods have the same implementation.

The Switch needs to be implemented twice one within the IF loop and the other for general case.

```
    public class selector8
{
      public static void main (String [] args){

    selector8 obj1 = new selector8();
    Scanner inputString = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner inputYN = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input, A,B,C;

    System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
    input = inputString.nextLine();
    char contLoop1 = 'y';
    do{
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            input = "";
            System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
            input = inputString.nextLine();
            switch (input){

            case("a"):
                obj1.startMethod1(input);
                break;

            case("b"):
                obj1.startMethod2(input);
                break;

            case("c"):
                obj1.startMethod3(input);
                break;

            case("x"):
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                break;

            case ("n"):
                System.out.println("See ya");
                break;

            default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid argument. Try again");
                    break;

                }
        } else
        switch (input){

        case("a"):
            obj1.startMethod1(input);
            break;

        case("b"):
            obj1.startMethod2(input);
            break;

        case("c"):
            obj1.startMethod3(input);
            break;

        case("x"):
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;

        case ("n"):
            System.out.println("See ya");
            break;

        default:
                System.out.println("Invalid argument. Try again");
                break;

            }
            System.out.println("Do want to try again " +"Y/N" );
            input = inputYN.nextLine(); 
            contLoop1 = input.charAt(0);
    }while(contLoop1 != 'n');
}

public void startMethod1(String A){
    String input;

    Scanner inputString = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a or b");
    input = inputString.nextLine();

    switch (input){

    case("a"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;

    case("b"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid argument");
    }
}

public void startMethod2(String B){

    String input;
    Scanner inputString = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a or b");
    input = inputString.nextLine();
    switch (input){
    case("a"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;
    case("b"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid argument");
        break;
    }
}

public void startMethod3(String C){

    String input;
    Scanner inputString = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a or b");
    input = inputString.nextLine();
    switch (input){
    case("a"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;
    case("b"):
        System.out.println("output parsed");
    break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid argument");
    }
}
}
```

On a side note could you also tell me why can static classes be called without an object?

```
public class StaticImplementation{
public static void main (String [] args){
StaticImplementation obj1 = new StaticImplementation();
obj1.stat(); //is invalid
stat(); //is valid
}
static void stat(){
    System.out.println("Static class");
}
```

Thanks a bunch. Have a good day!

Comment: You've got one loop.  It's plenty efficient.  It could do with some tidying up though (moving things into their own method, better naming conventions, etc).

Comment: @Makoto: I feel it looks messy to have two switch loops that perform the same function. Would like to know if its possible to perform the first IF loop function without the need for if(input.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"))

Comment: Well, it *is* messy.  That much is for sure.  If you have two statements (those are switch statements, the loop is also a statement), then refactor them into one method.  Then, see if you need the second method call at all.

Comment: @Makoto: thanks you provided a valuable input. I will refactor the switch loop into one method and call the method instead.

Comment: I think you need to follow few guidelines here, 1. If same task is performed in two different conditions, then put that task in a method.( eg startMethodX() perform same task), so no diff methods are needed. 2. If two switch case need to do same task, then club those cases. (here, cases in startMethodX() and in main()). 3. No need of new scanner in startMethodX(), you are passing the value to it i guess. So use that if that is the value you need to process. 4. Task done in if-else of main() is same, so no need of if-else there.

Answer (score 2):

using Java you'd probably take a more "Object Oriented" approach and leave those switches to C programming :)

do something like:

```
interface Action {
    void start();
}

class Jumper implements Action {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Jump!");
    }
}

class Sitter implements Action {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Sit!");
    }
}

class Runner implements Action {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Run!");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init phase
        Map<String, Action> map = new HashMap<String, Action>();
        map.put("a", new Jumper());
        map.put("b", new Runner());

        // usage
        map.get("a").start();
    }
}
```

you can have two Maps one for Y and the other for the rest, you can also have a key composed from the two strings Pair

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, it can. You don't need two scanners, and I would extract your switch into a method (let's call it `startMethods`) like so -

```
private static void startMethods(selector8 obj1,
    String input) {
  switch (input) {
  case ("a"):
    obj1.startMethod1(input);
    break;
  case ("b"):
    obj1.startMethod2(input);
    break;
  case ("c"):
    obj1.startMethod3(input);
    break;
  case ("x"):
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
    break;
  case ("n"):
    System.out.println("See ya");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Invalid argument. Try again");
    break;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  selector8 obj1 = new selector8();
  Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input, A, B, C;

  System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
  input = inputString.nextLine();
  char contLoop1 = 'y';
  do {
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
      input = "";
      System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
      input = inputString.nextLine();
      startMethods(obj1, input);
    } else
      startMethods(obj1, input);
    System.out.println("Do want to try again "
        + "Y/N");
    input = inputString.nextLine();
    contLoop1 = input.charAt(0);
  } while (contLoop1 != 'n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Selector8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Selector8 obj1 = new Selector8();
        Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputYN = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input, A, B, C;

        System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
        input = inputString.nextLine();
        char contLoop1 = 'y';
        while (contLoop1 != 'n') {
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Choose. A || B || C || X to exit");
                input = inputString.nextLine();
            } 
            switch (input) {

            case ("a"):
            case ("b"):
            case ("c"):
                obj1.startMethod();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(validate(input));
                break;

            }
            System.out.println("Do want to try again " + "Y/N");
            input = inputYN.nextLine();
            contLoop1 = input.charAt(0);
        }
    }

    public static String validate(String input) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
            return "Goodbye";

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            return "See ya";

        return "Invalid argument. Try again";
    }

    public void startMethod() {
        Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a or b");
        String input = inputString.nextLine();

        switch (input) {
        case ("a"):
        case ("b"):
            System.out.println("output parsed");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid argument");
        }
    }
}
```